# EXC_BAD_ACCESS after data is passed on

Tags: objective-c, ipad, exc-bad-access

I'm currently working on an iPad App for the management of aircraft fleets. I want to read the data from an XML file using NSXMLParser, which creates "Airplane" instances containing the data. The NSXMLParser as well as the NSXMLParserDelegate are children of the App Delegate. I am using a Tab View Layout. The parsing itself works just fine. An NSMutableArray containing the Aircraft objects is passed on to the Tab View Controllers. The problem is that from within the Tab View Controllers, the properties of the "Airplane" objects can't be accessed, resulting in an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" warning. However, when accessed from the App Delegate class, it works just fine. This is the property definition in the delegate class:

```
@property (copy, readonly) NSMutableArray* airplanes;
```

It is passed on to the view controller like this:

```
fleetViewController.airplanes = delegate.airplanes;
```

The property definition in the fleetViewController:

```
@property (copy, readwrite) NSMutableArray *airplanes;
```

And this is the part that throws the exception:

```
registration = [[airplanes objectAtIndex:0] registration];
```

As I said, when that same method is called from the App Delegate, it works without any trouble.

Help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If you are using properties, you should always set their value using the `self.propertyName` notation. This makes sure that internally the memory management is done properly.

If you have `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` this means that you are accessing invalid memory. To address such problems it is quite helpful to run your App in Profile mode and check for "Zombies":

I find this alternative more convenient:

1. Click the "Run Button Dropdown"
2. From the list choose `Profile`
3. The program "Instruments" should open where you can also choose `Zombies`
4. Now you can interact with your app and try to cause the error
5. As soon as the error happens you should get a hint on when your object was released and therefore deallocated.

[image: Zombies]
<sub>(source: [dimzzy.com](http://www.dimzzy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/leaky-zombies-tool.png))</sub>

Comment: While true, you should avoid using `self.` in initialisers and dealloc.

Comment: Hmm.. somehow my Instruments doesn't seem to be working properly, when I run it in "Profile" mode, the error can't be reproduced, instead nothing happens at all, now the object is not even passed on.

Comment: UPDATE: I noticed that I had the properties in the Airplanes class set to "copy". Since there isn't actually a need for that I changed it to "retain" with surprising results: The error now doesn't occur in a regular manner anymore, it pops up all over the code, never at the same spot twice in a row. Sometimes no error occurs at all, and about half of the NSString is returned. For example, one airplane's registration is "HB-CHX" and "HB-C" is returned. The weirdest I've had so far was that "German.lproj" was returned. This does not make sense to me.. Anyone?